# Interactive Perl programming in Sublime 3 (Ubuntu)

Tags: perl, ubuntu, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

Practically all of the exercises in my introductory Perl book have so far required taking input, which is causing me some challenges with Sublime Text 3. I set up the custom build file from this [post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=935014) to run scripts directly and I've also installed REPL on top of that, but I'm still unable to provide input through the bottom console.

Is there a way to enable input for scripts built via Ctrl+B, preferably with the console messages getting a little less in the way? I'm currently stuck with having to fire up the terminal every time, which doesn't make for a particularly smooth learning experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really help you with your Sublime issue, but you mention firing up a terminal every time isn't helping you learn - here's the way I do it when I'm either learning or rapidly prototyping: Simply setup a folder on your local machine, called *sync* or something. Create a similar folder on your terminal server.

Now use an app (I use WinSCP and use Keep Remote Directory Up To Date setting) to sync. Every time you press save in your text editor, the new script is automatically uploaded to your terminal server, you can now just alt+tab to your terminal and run the script. Works very well for me and enabled really easy rapid prototyping.